# Expected str, got base exception

Tags: python, ironpython

I'm parsing a bin file to an array, but it got base exception error, how do I slove this ? The error happens at dataY.append(var[1]),

but I have wrote a try except to catch the var[1], it looks correct.

var is a tuple that contains two double read from .bin file

```
@staticmethod
def __loadBin(filepath,validate = False):

    file =  open(filepath,'rb') 

    dataX = []
    dataY = []
    array = []
    rows = 0 
    fileContent = file.read(16)

    while len(fileContent) == 16 :


        var = struct.unpack('dd',fileContent)

        fileContent = file.read(16) 

        dataX.append(var[0])

        dataY.append(var[1]) # Here 

        rows +=1 
        if rows % 12072752 == 0:

            dataX = []
            dataY = []

    #array.append([dataX,dataY])


    return array
```

The error says "expected str, got BaseException", I don't know why it expect a string here, and I did't found anything online talk about this error

However, when I comment out either of  **dataY.append(var[1])** or **dataX.append(var[0])**

the method works well

I'm using ironpython to do a wpf project, and the error happens in this method

**Update**

**Does anyone know about this error ? I got it more than once in visual studio 2017, under ironpython wpf project**

Comment: Just to let you know: You got no answers because you did not provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot help you because we simply don't see the same error. Learning how to provide minimal reproducible examples within the question will help you get better answers to your future questions.